# Footnote numbering when using paracol package

Tags: footnotes, paracol

I have a document where footnote numbers restart every page, when I use the paracol environment this seems to stop working. In my MWE the footnotes in each page are okay for normal text but the second paracol environment numbers the footnotes as 3 and 4 instead of 1 and 2 even though it is on a new page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\setcounter{footnote}{0}} % resets footnote counter on every page

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
    this is the first page\footnote{footnote 1 page 1}
    \pagebreak%

    second page\footnote{footnote 1 page2}
    \pagebreak%

    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
        \setlength{\columnsep}{15pt}

        left column     
        \switchcolumn%  
        right column\footnote{a footnote}\\%

        \switchcolumn*% 
        left column again

        \switchcolumn%      
        right column again\footnote{2nd footnote}\\%
    \end{paracol} 
    \pagebreak%

    another page with normal text\footnote{and a footnote} 
    \pagebreak%

    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
        \setlength{\columnsep}{15pt}

        left column     
        \switchcolumn%  
        right column\footnote{a footnote}\\%

        \switchcolumn*% 
        left column again

        \switchcolumn%      
        right column again\footnote{2nd footnote}\\%
    \end{paracol} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414513/paracol-how-to-reset-footnote-counter-every-page-worst-case?s=3|61.9852